# Laravel. Edit user with relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I want make form edit user. For the present moment I can edit the data from the user table, but I would like to assign power to the user roles, from the table roles (dropdownlist).

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('roles')->get();
    return view('pages.user', compact('users'));
}
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $user = User::with('roles')->findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    return redirect('users');
}
```

**Form**

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action'=>['UsersController@update', $user->id]]) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name','Name: ') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Here, user name']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('roles','Roles: ') !!}
                        {!! Form::select('roles',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                        {!! Form::select('roles',$user,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!} 
//i try this but still not working
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thx for help.

Comment: From your above code, I damn sure you facing undefined `$user` variable issue. Correct? if not then provide respective code to proper investigation of cause.

Comment: I added the code to the controller, but I'm not sure if this is it.

Comment: I found something similar, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283522/laravel-foreign-keys-drop-down-list


But I can not properly apply it.

Comment: Now what you want is, display the all role into dropdown right?

Comment: Yes i would like to show the roles. After this, I would like to change the role of the user to another on the list

Comment: Ok, wait for moment writing the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want display all role into 'Role' droppdown, check below change of code:
**Controller**

```
public function index()
{   
    //Get user detail
    $users = User::with('roles')->get();

    //Get all roles
    $userRole = Roles::lists('name','id');
    return view('pages.user', compact('users', 'userRole'));
}
```

**Form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('roles','Roles: ') !!}
    {!! Form::select('roles',$userRole, null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}<!-- replace with $users['role_id'], if want to display selected role-->
</div>
```

**NOTE:** use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) instead of list for laravel >= 5.3. The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature remains the same.

Let me know if still not working!

Comment: It works but lists is undefinied. I swapped lists() on pluck().

Comment: Oh, great...Glad to help...:)

Comment: I can ask you one more question? I added this dropdown but he only shows the list. When I click on buttun "send" my database doesn't change.

Form::text change my database, but Form::select doesn't make any changes. Maybe, i have a problem in the controller?

Comment: Yes, why not? I can help you for this too, but the better way is create a new question and then I'll put my efforts at there so that other people can get solution if required...